# pandas import csvs with '"' and ',' as values in a csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a csv that has an entry like this:

```
"432983278.2","3764",""The CITY TOW" of San Francisco, CA","",""...
```

that is, there is a comma and a couple quotes within that one entry that should be picked up as `"THE CITY TOW" of San Francisco, CA`
I don't have the option of regenerating this csv

I tried `pandas.read_csv("thefile.csv",quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, quotechar = '"')` and some different encodings and quoting options but this still can't be handled.

Comment: can you change it to a tsv or some other format?

What happens when you just `pd.read_csv('path.csv')`?

Comment: it runs into an unrelated error after a few lines of reading that is a result of quotes inside the cell (without any comma). when I use `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` it reads 38k lines before getting this error

Comment: can you post some of the data here? maybe use the QUOTE_ALL argument and then just get the first 15 lines or so?

Comment: That format is badly malformed. Like, bash-head-on-desk-to-recover-data-malformed. I'm not convinced you can faithfully reproduce the original

Comment: You can try error_bad_lines=False

Comment: Is it just this single line? You may have a shot if the rest of the file is valid but if this is a recurring issue, I'm not so sure.

Comment: this is one line 38k lines into the file

Comment: Ah, then focus on the other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

If it's only a few lines, can you just ignore those lines?

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("thefile.csv", error_bad_lines=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is the unwanted double quotes**. However, if you look at the pattern, (`","`) appears to be a delimiter which could give you what you want.

Since all the columns of your data are strings, you can import the csv to a pandas dataframe with `dtype=str` & with `sep='","'`

```
"432983278.2","3764",""The CITY TOW" of San Francisco, CA","",""...
```

**Try using:**

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep='","', dtype=str)
```